# Modify event attributes during propagation

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

### Problem

Basically, I am wondering if it is possible to change the attributes of an event that subsequent handlers will pick up.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9QZ2a/ (need debug console open)

I am trying to modify the `clientX` attribute of the event in the capturing phase on my container and have my change be reflected in the event fired in the bubbling phase on the target element.

### Back Story

I have a Google Maps element in a scaled overlay on iOS (it is scaled so that my overlay always "looks" the same size no matter what zoom level you are at - as it is for advertising which requires this).

The map works perfectly at 100% zoom, but as soon as you zoom into the page the overlay (containing the map) is then scaled - using CSS3 `scale`. This causes the events to be off position when interacting with the map, e.g. if you try to pinch zoom the center of the map, it actually zooms into the top left.

I believe I can fix this by scaling the event coordinates before the event is caught by the maps API.

As I cannot change the Google Maps API, I am limited to trying to find a solution in my container code.

Thanks!

**Edit:** The underlying issue I was trying to solve is actually a bug in the Google Maps API :( http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4046

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this, event proprties are read-only. For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent . Have you tried to solve the problem by setting `transform-origin`?

Comment: Hmmm I hadn't thought of that, I will give it a go :)

Comment: @Teemu yeah that's working :) Can you convert your comment to an answer so I can set it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this, event proprties are read-only: [MouseEvent in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent).

Have you tried to solve the problem by using CSS3 [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) and setting `transform-origin`?